How to avoid duplicate checkboxes in my LazyVerticalGrid in Jetpack Compose?
I'm trying to create a Bug Report screen. The user must enter a description of the Bug and can select various checkboxes. I then retrieve that information to write an email with it.
My problem is that the checkboxes are recreated when text is entered into the TextField or when the screen is rotated.
Why does this happen and how can I avoid it?
BugItems are fixed elements that I take in a resource array. I have created two data classes to represent the Bug Report.
data class BugReport(
    val message: String,
    val bugItems: List<BugItem>,
)

data class BugItem(
    val title: String,
    val completed: Boolean = false,
)

This is the composable of the Screen:
@ExperimentalFoundationApi
@Composable
fun BugReportScreen(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    val launcher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
        contract = ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
        onResult = { }
    )

    val message = remember { mutableStateOf("") }

    val bugItems = remember {
        mutableStateListOf<BugItem>()
    }

    stringArrayResource(id = R.array.bug_report).forEach {
        bugItems += BugItem(title = it, completed = false)
    }
    val bugReport = remember {
        mutableStateOf(BugReport(message.value, bugItems))
    }

    Box(
        modifier = modifier,
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
        ) {

            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .height(50.dp)
            )

            GenericToolbar(title = "Bug Report")
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)) 
            Text(text = stringResource(id = R.string.bug_intro))
            Text(text = stringResource(id = R.string.bug_description))

            TextFieldBugDescription(message)
            Text(text = stringResource(id = R.string.bug_check))    
            
            LazyVerticalGrid(
                modifier = Modifier.heightIn(max = 1000.dp),
                columns = GridCells.Fixed(2),
                content = {
                    items(bugReport.value.bugItems.size) { index ->
                        Row(
                            modifier = Modifier.padding(1.dp),
                            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
                        ) {

                            Checkbox(
                                checked = bugItems[index].completed,
                                onCheckedChange = { checked ->
                                    bugItems[index] = bugItems[index].copy(completed = checked)
                                }
                            )
                            Text(
                                text = bugItems[index].title,
                                style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyLarge,
                            )
                        }
                    }

                }

            )
            Text(text = stringResource(id = R.string.bug_send))
            Row(
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            ) {
                LPlusButton(
                    onClick = {
                        sendEmail(launcher, bugReport)
                    },
                    text = { Text(text = stringResource(R.string.send_email)) },
                    leadingIcon = {
                        Icon(
                            imageVector = LPlusIcons.Email,
                            contentDescription = stringResource(R.string.send_email)
                        )
                    },
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(horizontal = 24.dp)
                        .widthIn(364.dp)
                        .fillMaxWidth(),
                )
            }
        }
    }
}


@Composable
fun TextFieldBugDescription(message: MutableState<String>) {
    TextField(
        value = message.value,
        onValueChange = { message.value = it },
        label = { Text(stringResource(id = R.string.bug_label)) },
        maxLines = 2,
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(20.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(200.dp)
    )
}

As you can see in this first screenshot, the checkboxes are correct:

But when I activate the TextField and type some text, the elements are recreated. And the same thing happens if I rotate the screen:


There are several issues in your code:

The stringArrayResource will be executed every time the parent Composable recomposes, which always adds more and more BugItems to the bugItems list
You initialize bugReport with message.value, but you don't update it when the message changes.
You are passing a MutableState<String> to your TextFieldBugDescription Composable, which is not recommended.

It is expected that any state is lost when rotating the device. To prevent that, either use rememberSaveable for types like String or Int or delegate all variables that should survive configuration changes into a ViewModel and expose them using a Flow and observing them in the Composable using collectAsStateWithLifecycle.
In your case, as you want to store and modify the bugItems list which is not supported natively by rememberSaveable, I would suggest to introduce a ViewModel class. In your case, you could even use an AndroidViewModel to directly initialize the BugItem list with the String array:
class BugViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

    // this is the internal modifyable variable
    private val _bugItems = MutableStateFlow<List<BugItem>>(emptyList())
    // this is the public readonly variable to be exposed to the Composable
    val bugItems: StateFlow<List<BugItem>> get() = _bugItems

    init {
        val bugsArray = application.resources.getStringArray(R.array.my_bugs)
        val initialBugItems = bugsArray.map { BugItem(title = it) }
        _bugItems.value = initialBugItems
    }

    fun updateBugItem(updatedItem: BugItem, newCompleted: Boolean) {
        val updatedList = _bugItems.value.map { item ->
            if (item.title == updatedItem.title) item.copy(completed = newCompleted) else item
        }
        _bugItems.value = updatedList
    }
}

Then, get the ViewModel using the viewModel() function and observe it in your Composable as follows:
fun BugReportScreen(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    bugViewModel: BugViewModel = viewModel()
) {

    //...
    val bugItems by bugViewModel.bugItems.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()

    //...
    Checkbox(
        checked = bugItems[index].completed,
        onCheckedChange = { checked ->
            bugViewModel.updateBugItem(bugItems[index], checked)
        }
    )
}

Then, only assemble the bugReport at the very moment of submission:
onClick = {
    sendEmail(launcher, BugReport(message.value, bugItems))
},

And finally, change your TextFieldBugDescription to
@Composable
fun TextFieldBugDescription(message: String, onMessageChanged: (String) -> Unit) {
    TextField(
        value = message.value,
        onValueChange = onMessageChanged,
        label = { Text(stringResource(id = R.string.bug_label)) },
        maxLines = 2,
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(20.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(200.dp)
    )
}

and call it as
TextFieldBugDescription(
    message = message.value,
    onMessageChanged = { newMessage ->
        message.value = newMessage
    }
)


Thank you very much for your answer. I have moved the BugReport content to a ViewModel and it works perfectly. Since I am using Hilt, instead of AndroidViewModel I have put the annotation @HiltViewModel and injected the context in the constructor with @ApplicationContext private val context: Context and in the composable: bugViewModel: BugViewModel = hiltViewModel().

In LazyVerticalGrid content items() use key parameter and assign key id so compose will display unique key items.
LazyVerticalGrid(
            modifier = Modifier.heightIn(max = 1000.dp),
            columns = GridCells.Fixed(2),
            content = {
                items(key = specificId, count = bugReport.value.bugItems.size) { index ->
                    Row(
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(1.dp),
                        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
                    ) {

                        Checkbox(
                            checked = bugItems[index].completed,
                            onCheckedChange = { checked ->
                                bugItems[index] = bugItems[index].copy(completed = checked)
                            }
                        )
                        Text(
                            text = bugItems[index].title,
                            style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyLarge,
                        )
                    }
                }

            }

        )

